# Load .dat file with pandas, make two columns where '\' is separator

Tags: python, pandas

How to load .dat file in two columns with slash as separator with pandas library?

```
0     NaN\t1.000000      NaN
1     0.00\t-3.0         NaN
2     0.04\t-4.9         NaN
3     0.08\t-4.47        NaN
```

With code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("dummy.dat", sep="\",skiprows = 0)
```

I get an error

```
File "<ipython-input-7-8a49552b5bf1>", line 6 df = pd.read_csv("dummy.dat", sep="\", header=None, skiprows=0) ^
```

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Post the full error message. Is it a syntax error?

Comment: Is the separator the backslash or `\t`? `\t` is a common representation of the tab character. Depending on how you looked at this data, you may be looking at a tab separator, not `\t`. Since python uses backslash as an escape character, you need to do `\\\` to get the one single character. The first backslash tells python to treat the second one as a literal backslash.

Comment: But still, put the full traceback message in the question so that its a complete statement of the problem.

Comment: With:   df = pd.read_csv("dummy.dat", sep='\\', header=None, skiprows=0)
It prints the data without error, but in one column. I would like the backslash to be the separator if it is possible

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Code is unreadable in comments. Also, comments tend to appear in order of votes, not chronologically. Make it easy to help you and easy for others with the same problem by putting everything in one place --- the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your syntax highlighting, it is your friend:

```
df = pd.read_csv("dummy.dat", sep="\",skiprows = 0)
```

See how the right bracket after skiprows is not coloured the same was as the opening bracket? That's a hint that there is a problem in between.

Using `separator="\"` you *have escaped the* `"` rather than making a closing quote. Compare it with

```
df = pd.read_csv("dummy.dat", sep="\"",skiprows = 0)
```

In any case, your separator is `\t` *not* `\`, for at least part of your data, so try

```
df = pd.read_csv("dummy.dat", sep='\t',skiprows = 0)
```

You should clean up your data before importing it, however. It looks like you have a mix of *tab characters* (we can see between columns) and escaped tabs (which we see between columns 2 and 3, as in `0.00\t-3.0`). If you convert those escaped `\t` to actual tabs.